# Why is the output of my XML file appendin a '/>'

Tags: java, xml

Here is my dilemma:

I have an XML, where I want to insert animation_sequence,however, instead the code adds animation_sequnce/> with an opening angle bracket, I can add all other elements but that one. Why is that? I tried adding the XML here but it wouldn't render. Here is my code:

```
    Element state = testDoc.createElement("state");
    state.setTextContent(element);
    Element animationState = testDoc.createElement("animation_state");
    Element sequence = testDoc.createElement("animation_sequence");

    testDoc.getElementsByTagName("animations_list").item(0).appendChild(animationState).appendChild(state);
    testDoc.getElementsByTagName("animation_state").item(testDoc.getElementsByTagName("state").getLength() - 1).appendChild(sequence);
```

Comment: I apologize but I didn't know 'support' was that important, I just joined the site a few weeks so I'm still learning to traverse the site and learn it's functionality. I promise I will select the best answer, now that you guys taught me about it.

Comment: Oh , I didn't checked his profile . I saw 11 repo and thought he must be a new bee. my mistake , guys .

Comment: Sorry to be prickly, afturk.khan, thanks for understanding.  I'll try to be more forgiving in the future and use a more constructive method of communicating :)

Comment: While I learn about the culture of this website, can somebody please help me? I've spent hours on this . . .

Comment: Stephen, please grow up. I was just notified earlier by Steve about the 'accept' functionality which I didn't know about, and eloquently said I will start using it. No need to bring it up till eternity, in life we forgive and move on. Being prickly is not a good trait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have shown us creates nodes in a tree. It doesn't append any angle brackets to anything. Angle brackets only appear when you serialize the tree (convert it to lexical XML). Generally the system takes care of how to serialize the XML, and you don't need to worry when it chooses between different ways of serializing it because when the XML is parsed the differences won't matter.

Now it could be that the "/>" is a symptom that the tree you have built isn't the tree that you intended to build, but that's a different matter.

Comment: Hi Michael, that doesn't exactly answer my question. Why can't I add <animation_sequence> </animation_sequence> to the tree?

Comment: The tree doesn't contain tags, it contains nodes. You can add an animation_sequence element to the tree, but you can't add start tags and end tags.

Comment: So why was I able to add other tags using the same code? For example, the code corresponding state adds a <state> </state> and the same for animation state, its just the animation sequence that acts weird.